# Search exe file for English words

Tags: search, dictionary, hex-editor

I am trying to find out if there are open source components in an app I found online. I have skimmed the file in a Hex editor but can't spend the hours that would be required going line by line looking for any unencrypted words that may exist helping this quest. Is there an app (Preferrably portable) out there to search a file using a dictionary list as a source?

Comment: Sorry, OS looking to use said program on is Windows 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on *nix, the `strings` command does what you want.

This seems to do the same on windows: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439

Comment: Looks very nice and just right. Cheers!